# How to log multiple threads in different log files?

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

I have a JAVA class that starts various threads that have unique IDs.
Each thread should log into a unique log file, named after the ID.log.

Because I only get the unique ID at runtime, I have to configure Log4J programatically:

```
// Get the jobID
myJobID = aJobID;
// Initialize the logger
myLogger = Logger.getLogger(myJobID);
FileAppender myFileAppender;
try
{
    myFileAppender = new FileAppender(new SimpleLayout(), myJobID + ".log", false);
    BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
    BasicConfigurator.configure(myFileAppender);
} catch (IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now this works fine if I start jobs sequentially - but when I start 2 threads (of the same class) simultaneously, both logs are created but the logs are mixed up: The second thread logs into the first as well as the second log.

How could I make sure that each instance is unique ?
I already tried to give a unique name to each logger instance, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Is there a really good reason you want to do this distinction in the java code? General practice is to keep log in one file and then run some post processing to extract/aggregate? Also refer to http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.1

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I setup log4j properties so that each thread outputs to its own log file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1172113/127035)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Logback has a special appender called [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) which provides a very nice solution to the type of problems you describe. A SiftingAppender can be used to separate (or sift) logging according to any runtime attribute, including thread id.

Comment: Is there any java implementation to do the same as this https://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-different-log-file-for-each-thread/

i.e. to have sifting appender to do the same as described in that blog.

Comment: The link you show is entirely based on logback's SiftingAppender.

Comment: Hmm. Got it. can we have multiple siftingAppenders.  Basically I need two loggers to write to two different locations. Both will be used in separate threads, so has to use sifting I think. But when I have two it wont work anyway. I'm having 2 MDC values as well.

Comment: Hmm I'm doing this,
`LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
context.reset();`

And I'm doing this before creating each Appenders and use that context to set those appenders. But then only one Appender will work. But if I have a common `context` for both then both will work.

Any idea why it does that ?

Comment: Hint: What do you think context.reset() does?

Comment: Clear any previous configuration. Hmm is that the problem here.

Answer (score 12):

For log4j v2 you can use [RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to dynamically route messages. You can put value for key 'threadId' into the ThreadContext map and then use this id as a part of the file name. There is an example which I have easily applied for the same purpose as yours. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files

Be aware when putting values into ThreadContext map: "A child thread automatically inherits a copy of the mapped diagnostic context of its parent." So if you have put a value for key 'threadId' into the parent thread and eventually created multiple threads from it, then all child threads will inherit the value of 'threadId' value. I was not able to simply override this value by using `put()` one more time - you need to use `ThreadContext.clear()` or explicitly `remove()` the value from thread context map.

Here is my working log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
    <properties>
        <property name="logMsgPattern">%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level - %msg%n</property>
        <property name="logDir">test logs</property><!-- ${sys:testLogDir} -->
    </properties>
    <appenders>
         <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">           
            <PatternLayout pattern="${logMsgPattern}"/>
         </Console>

        <Routing name="Routing">
                    <Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadId}">             
                        <Route>
                            <RollingFile name="RollingFile-${ctx:threadId}" fileName="${logDir}/last-${ctx:threadId}.log" filePattern="${logDir}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/archived_%d{HH-mm}-${ctx:threadId}.log">
                                    <PatternLayout pattern="${logMsgPattern}"/>
                                    <Policies>
                                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                            </Policies> 
                    </RollingFile>
                        </Route>
                    </Routes>
            </Routing>  
    </appenders>

    <loggers>               
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" level="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="Routing" level="debug"/>
        </root>                     
    </loggers>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

@havexz 's approach is quite good: [writing everything to the same log file and using nested diagnostic contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.1).

If your concern is about several JVMs writing to the same FileAppender, then i'd suggest two things:

- [using SLF4J as a logging facade](http://www.slf4j.org/)
- using [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as logging implementation, [in prudent mode](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudent)

> In prudent mode, FileAppender will safely write to the specified file,
>   even in the presence of other FileAppender instances running in
>   different JVMs, potentially running on different hosts.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the snippet of the Routing code from a working log4j.xml file.

```
<Appenders>

        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %-50logger{4}: %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
                <Routes pattern="${ctx:logFileName}">


                    <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has a value for logFileName. 
                        The value dynamically determines the name of the log file. -->

                    <Route>
                        <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:logFileName}"
                            fileName="${sys:log.path}/${ctx:logFileName}.javalog"
                            filePattern="./logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/${ctx:logFileName}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                            <PatternLayout>
                                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %-50logger{4}: %msg%n</pattern>
                            </PatternLayout>
                            <Policies>
                                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6"
                                    modulate="true" />
                                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                            </Policies>
                        </RollingFile>
                    </Route>

                    <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has no value for key logFileName. -->
                    <Route key="${ctx:logFileName}" ref="ConsoleAppender" />

                </Routes>
            </Routing>
</Appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="RoutingAppender" level="debug" />
        </root>
    </loggers>
```

The key 'logFileName' can be added to the thread context map in the run() method of the Runnable class as follows,

```
public class SomeClass implements Runnable{

 private int threadID;

 public SomeClass(int threadID){
   this.threadID=threadID;
   }
 @Override
 public void run() {
    String logFileName = "thread_log_"+ threadID;
    ThreadContext.put("logFileName", logFileName);
    //Some code
    ThreadContext.remove("threadId");
   }
}
```

In addition, the correct log4j packages must be imported, as shown below.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;
```

Please note that the following imports will not work. LogManager and Logger must also come from org.apache.logging.log4j.

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) API was designed to do what you describe.

Code like below would establish per-thread loggers each using own (per-thread) FileAppender:

```
/**
 * usage: threadLocalLogger.get().info("hello thread local logger")
 */
static ThreadLocal<Logger> threadLocalLogger = newThreadLocalLogger("myJobId");

private static ThreadLocal<Logger> newThreadLocalLogger(final String myJobID) {
    return new ThreadLocal<Logger>() {
        @Override
        protected Logger initialValue() {
            return logger(myJobID, Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    };
}

private static Logger logger(String myJobID, long threadId) {
    // Initialize the logger
    String loggerId = myJobID + "-" + threadId;
    Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger(loggerId);
    FileAppender myFileAppender;
    try
    {
        myFileAppender = new FileAppender(new SimpleLayout(),
                loggerId + ".log", false);
        BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
        BasicConfigurator.configure(myFileAppender);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myLogger;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a static instance counter variable to your class. Then you would need a synchronized method which increases the counter for each object created and create the log file name from that value. Something like this:

```
class yourClass {

  private static int cnt = 0;

  public yourClass(){
    ...
    initLogger();
  }

  private synchronized initLogger(){
     yourClass.cnt++;
     myJobid = yourClass.cnt;

     //include your logging code here
  }
}
```

Comment: My JobID is a simple UUID. The problem is no the name of the log file, but the appenders which get mixed up.

Comment: I found this: http://www.manniwood.com/log4j_stuff/index.html but it implies that I have to know how many jobs (threads) will be started.