# log4j using different log files mixed up

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j

Dears,

Currently i'm running an web application which uses log4j for logging purposes. My application use Multi-threading concept and my log4j works fine if threads are started in sequential.

If i start multitasking then 1st thread log are logged into 2nd task thread and vice-versa. Hence the logs are mixed up.

While calling another methods of every class i'm just passing my appender as an arguments. And i am calling the appender as below in every class as required

```
private FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();
log.addAppender(appender);
```

How can i differentiate the appender log files based on task that are started in parallel.

Thanks

Comment: you should show some code, to understand

Comment: In each and every class i'm calling ` Logger log = Logger.getLogger(classname.class); FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();` So the instance is static and the logs are getting mixed up

Comment: AFAIK, appenders are better to configure in `log4j.properties` file. This way you may end up with many orphaned appenders for one logger (if not to call `removeAppender`). Anyway, I would suggest to synchronize adding appender to logger: `synchronized(log){ log.addAppender(appender); }`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to match the logged string with the thread origin.
You can use Nested Diagnostic Context (see 
http://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-ndc-log4j, and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22150615/7670475
.