# Thread specific logging with log4j

Tags: multithreading, log4j2

We have a large java application that accepts jobs via various means, runs them, and returns the result.  Currently, there is a single log4j log collecting all the logging.  We want to keep this, but add:

Job specific logging.  When a job starts, start a new log file, and append to it from any thread that is part of the Job thread tree.  (each job does start in it's own thread.)  We ALSO need to be able to specify the Log Level to be used for that log. When the job completes, we will send the log back with the job results. (yes, zipped)

I think I've figured out how to handle the LogLevel via ThreadContextMapFilter, and it looks like I can use a Routing definition to choose which log file to write the data to.
See [log4 routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761294/configuring-log4j2-for-threads)

One question is how do I tell log4j to stop logging to the file and flush the buffers so I can read the file?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up.  As far as I can tell, once Routing Appender creates a new RandomAccessFileAppender - it exists forever, and there isn't any way to have it close and be discarded.
I wrote a private appender that allows listeners to collect the log lines, and filter them on their own.

Answer (score 0):

To stop an appender instantiated by the `RoutingAppender`, you need to call [`RoutingAppender#deleteAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/routing/RoutingAppender.html#deleteAppender-java.lang.String-) in your code:

```java
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final RoutingAppender appender = ctx.getConfiguration().getAppender("Routing");
appender.deleteAppender(key);
// wait until the appender stops
```

You can also create a custom [`PurgePolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/routing/PurgePolicy.html) implementation that will be notified, whenever an appender receives a message. The default policy just stops the appenders that have been idle for some configurable amount of time.

**Remark**: after calling `RoutingAppender#deleteAppender` the appender will **not** stop immediately. It will first log the messages that are currently being appender (possibly in other threads), so either use a long enough timeout or wait for the subappender to actually stop. You can retrieve a snapshot of the appenders with `RoutingAppender#getAppenders()` before you call `delete`.

**Remark 2**: if your jobs run in an isolated environment (e.g. a separate classloader), you might create a `LoggerContext` per job instead of using `RoutingAppender`. This will solve the problem of propagating the job id between threads.