# Workflow logging using Log4J

Tags: logging, log4j, workflow

I have defined two loggers MainLogger, SecondLogger which logs the debug statements
to two separate files Main.log and Second.log respectively and defined the categories
like

```
<appender name="MainLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="Main.log" />
</appender>

<appender name="SecondLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="Second.log" />
</appender>

<category name="Fully.Qualified.ClassA" additivity="false">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="MainLogger" />
    </category>

<category name="Fully.Qualified.ClassB" additivity="false">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="SecondLogger" />
</category>
```

The issue is, both the work flows share the ClassA and ClassB. So the Main.log is filled
with high traffic work flow which is difficult to manage.

How do I limit the work flows to go to respective log files only?

Is there any solution to route the current thread log statements to one particular log file only?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like it might be solvable using the technique [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172113/how-do-i-setup-log4j-properties-so-that-each-thread-outputs-to-its-own-log-file) is using.

Basically, it looks like he's programatically setting up new appenders for every threaded instance of the class.