# Log4j - file log for each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

I have a program that once started, it will executed a flow (few classes involved) several times - each in a different thread. The flow is the same - just different parameters sent to it each time it is invoked.

Each flow will execute on its own thread.

I want to be able to define a file appender (essentially file log) for each thread - so once a flow starts, it programmatically creates its own log file and writes to it.

Searched for it but couldnt find a simple solution for it
Can you help?

Ta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this programmatically. e.g.:

```java
class Task implements Runnable {

    private final String path;
    private final String name;

    public Task(String path, String name) {
        this.path = path;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Create file appender
        FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();
        appender.setFile(path);
        appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"));
        appender.activateOptions();

        // Get logger and add appender
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
        logger.setAdditivity(false);
        logger.addAppender(appender);

        // Task
        logger.info("Hello World!");

        // Remove appender
        logger.removeAppender(appender);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Task("logs/A.log", "com.company.A")).start();
    new Thread(new Task("logs/B.log", "com.company.B")).start();
}
```

Comment: You nailed it. Appreciate it paul

Answer (score 0):

1. Define handlers for each log file in the log4j file, for example, this way:
2. Now add something like this in the same xml file:

   ```
       <logger category="a.b.c.d">
           <level name="INFO"/>
           <handlers>
               <handler name="a.b.c.d_FILE"/>
           </handlers>
   ```

Comment: Wanted to create that progrematically as I dont know the amount of threads upfront - see Paul's answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of those solutions would fit your requirements

- [How do I setup log4j properties so that each thread outputs to its own log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172113/how-do-i-setup-log4j-properties-so-that-each-thread-outputs-to-its-own-log-file)
- [How to log multiple threads in different log files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355847/how-to-log-multiple-threads-in-different-log-files)
- [Log4j: One log file per request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331128/log4j-one-log-file-per-request)

There some others on http://stackoverflow.com ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by yourself:

```
RandomAccessFile logfile;

public void initLogger(String logPath) {
    File fl = new File(logPath);
    long fileLength = fl.length();
    logfile = new RandomAccessFile(fl, "rw");
    logfile.seek(fileLength);
}

public void log(String text) throws IOException {
    logfile.writeChars(text);
    logfile.writeChar('\n');
}
```